# Need some advice for a promise in a promise and how to write it better

Tags: node.js, promise

So my code is hopefully kinda straightforward (still learning don't hate me), I use a package to get the colorpallete of the image I feed it to. And since I need to wait to actually make it happen I need to wait when it's done.

Well my problem is I use a then in my then, and it feels really dirty and probably is not the right way to do this. Since it's a school project I don't really mind performance on first but if somebody can give me some advice how to make this a little more usuable. And I know I return it to the next promise it doesn't make sense since it's out of the other chain

I hope I kinda said it the right way haha. And if there are some articles I missed how to solve this would be great also!

```
.then(response => {
  // Make copy of the response
  const bookObject = response

  // Loop through each book
  bookObject.forEach((book, index) => {

    // Find the color pallete
    splashy.fromUrl(book.coverImage)
    .then(dominantColors => {

      // Create new key and add it to the list
      bookObject[index].dominantColors = dominantColors
    })
  })

  // Pass through to 
  return bookObject
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you aren't making a copy of the response, you're just creating an extra reference to it. You don't actually need it.

You're using a loop and executing an action for each item in the array, but you actually want to transform them to Promises that resolve with your changes. For this you should use `.map()` for something like:

```
// Loop through each book
return Promise.all(response.map(book =>
  // Find the color palette
  splashy.fromUrl(book.coverImage).then(
    dominantColors => {
      // Create new key and add it to the list
      book.dominantColors = dominantColors
      return book;
    })
));
```

What this does is transform your response into an array of Promises where each Promise resolves to the book with `dominantColors` added to it. Wrapping this with `Promise.all()` changes this from an array of Promises to one Promise that resolves to an array with your results.

Comment: Wow, yeah this is what I was looking for and I understand it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using at least Node version 7.6.0, you can use `async/await` to simplify this code. If you are able to wrap this code in an `async` function, it could look something like this:

```
async function myFunction() {
  const response = await functionThatReturnsResponse();
  const bookObject = response
  const morePromises = bookObject.map((book, index) => {
    splashy.fromUrl(book.coverImage)
      .then(dominantColors => {
        bookObject[index].dominantColors = dominantColors;
      });
  });

  await Promise.all(morePromises);

  return bookObject;
}
```

References:
`async/await`: https://javascript.info/async-await
`Promise.all()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1):

If you return a Promise inside a .then call it will be added to the Promise chain allowing you to continue chaining calls at the top level.

```
const call = (arg) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(arg));
call(1)
  .then((a) => call(a))
  .then((a) => console.log(a, 'Finished!')) // 1 Finished!
```

However your use case is a bit more complicated as you execute multiple async actions inside the then call. You need to group them all into a single Promise with Promise.all

```
const call = (arg) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(arg));
call(6)
  .then(() => {
    const args = [2,3,4];
    const promises = args.map((arg) => call(arg));  // Execute the async function and store the promise into the resulting array.
    return Promise.all(promises);  // Waits for every promise in the array to complete before continuing.
  })
  .then((results) => console.log(results.join(' '), 'Finished!')) // 2 3 4 Finished!
```